# How to get 5.4+ Kernel on Mint 19.3?

Tags: linux-mint, kernel

I just upgraded to a 3rd gen Ryzen processor for rendering and I can't monitor CPU temps. Apparently, support for this is added in Kernel 5.4. Update Manager says the system is up to date, but I'm on 5.0.

Articles online mention "mainline" but say it's not for production use. How can I get an official/production/stable 5.4 kernel on 19.3? (besides "wait for the next OS release").

Comment: The latest stable kernel release for Mint 19.3 is v5.3. If you want something newer, try this: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-linux-kernel-5-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Comment: After adding the repo per the article, I get `Unable to locate package ukuu`.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @ajgringo619: yes

Comment: I just checked his website - https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/ - and it looks like the free version of *Ukuu* is no longer being developed.

Comment: Try psensor in repo. It will work for some processor. It works on my 3400G.

Answer (score 0):

In `applets` you can find `CPU TEMPERATURE INDICATOR`.

If you are freshening up your Update-manager so there is actually

kernel 5.3.0-45 to be installed.

Both working on my ryzen7 flawlessly.

Latest (all) kernels here: Index of /~kernel-ppa/mainline

Best before any action is a backup by `timeshift`.